# Correct way to say "always victorious"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

**TL;DR** Would "always victorious" be *semper vicit*? That's my naive translation. Context is *God Save the Queen*.

**Details:**

Apparently my entire life I've been singing a line in the first verse of *God Save the Queen* wrong. The line is "Send her victorious" but I somehow thought from a young age it was "Semper victorious" and no one's noticed as it sounds quite similar. (Lucky for me I realized my mistake before Charles acceded to the throne — people would have looked at me funny.)

Out of the blue many, many years later I thought to ask myself whether "victorious" sounded right for Latin, and of course, it doesn't. Various online sources give me *vicit*.

Would it be *semper vicit*? (Google Translate says "vicit semper," [with the comma] but is notoriously rubbish at Latin.) Latin has so many morphological changes depending on parts of speech and the subject of the sentence, etc., that I'm not sure if *vicit* should have a slightly different form. It's an indirect reference to Her Majesty, but as an adjective ("[she is] always victorious"), so I wouldn't think *victrix* would be relevant (being a noun if I'm not mistaken).

Context:

*God save our gracious Queen

Long live our noble Queen

God save the Queen

Send her victorious,   <=== The line I got wrong

Happy and glorious,

Long to reign over us

God save the Queen!*

Comment: I am so pleased to have found this post… I too have always sung “semper victorious”, it was only last weekend that someone called it out as they explained the changes being made to the National Anthem; “‘send her victorious’ will need to change”. Given that I mis-learned the lyrics before learning any Latin, I wonder how we both settled on this version?

Comment: @AlistairBlackmore - I'm glad I'm not the only one. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Semper vicit" means "he/she has always won/conquered" (with a perfective rather than a habitual aspect). "Vicit" is the 3rd person active indicative perfect of *vincere*, a verb.

"Victorious", the adjective, is *victoriosus*. In the feminine (nominative singular), that's *victoriosa*.

Your phrase can be translated as **semper victoriosa** (with an elided implied **est**, I suppose, which is also elided in the English). For Charles it'd be **semper victoriosus**.

Comment: Re *vicit*: oh, of course! The same form as in *tempus fugit*, one of my father's favourite sayings. Maybe that saying was part of why I didn't think *vicit* was correct. Thank you!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In "tempus fugit" the "fugit" is actually in the present tense, though the only difference between present and perfect in that case is whether the *u* is short or long. There we know it's short because it scans as short in Vergil's Georgica, though, from which the saying in taken.

Comment: That makes more sense. I was slightly struggling with how it could be "has always passed" without the habitual aspect. Answer: Because it isn't. :-) Really appreciate your thorough answer to such a basic question.

Comment: Correct as usual Cairnarvon. Let me also suggest *semper victrix* and *semper victor* as possible alternatives.

Comment: _Victoriosa_/_victoriosus_ sounds awkward, because I find very few instances in classical literature. I think @Figulus is right suggesting _semper victrix_ (feminine) / _semper victor_ (masculine) (no matter _victrix_/_victor_ may be used as nouns: they are used as adjectives here). _Vicit semper_ may also be right, but sounds less poetical.